# Switching to Theoretical Particle Physics as an Experimental Particle Physicist

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question, education

It is quite common for physicists to change research areas in the middle of their careers. However, given that currently there's a big difference between experimental particle physics and theoretical particle physics, has anyone successfully changed from being an experimental particle physicist to a theoretical particle physicist after obtaining a PhD? If so, how common is this?