# Switching from Research in Experimental Particle Physics to Theoretical Particle Physics

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question, education

It is quite common for physicists to change research areas in the middle of their careers. However, given that currently there's a big difference between experimental particle physics and theoretical particle physics, has anyone successfully changed from being an experimental particle physicist to a theoretical particle physicist after obtaining a PhD? If so, how common is this?

Comment: There is "phenomenology" too, that large grey zone in between the two extremes... so it really is a slippery slope from one to the other.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for [Academia.se], don't you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649715/2451

Comment: Hi The Gypsy King. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic The previous question was about String Theory and this question is about particle physics in general, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Note that career advice in general is not on-topic for our community.

Comment: @rob Then it's more appropriate to mark this question as "off-topic" than "duplicate".

Comment: I have been in HEP since the 1970s, and I do not know of such a switch. The basic reason in my opinion is that theoretical HEP needs an enormous background and facility in mathematics, and this must be gained during the PHD studies. , imo